# Convert scalar arguments to arrays, and check that lengths are equal

Tags: python, numpy

I've got a Python function that takes two arguments, `lat` and `lon`. These arguments can be either scalar values (`52.3`) or any sort of iterable (e.g. a list or a NumPy array).

At the beginning of my function I need to check what I've been given, and convert both arguments to arrays (if needed) and check that both arguments are the same length.

```
# Deal with scalar values
try:
    lat_count = len(lat)
except:
    lat = [lat]
    lat_count = 1

try:
    lon_count = len(lon)
except:
    lon = [lon]
    lon_count = 1

if lat_count != lon_count:
    raise ValueError("lan and lon arrays must be the same length")

lat = np.array(lat)
lon = np.array(lon)
```

It feels horribly messy, but I can't work out how to make it better. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`np.atleast_1d` handles the conversion in one step.  It's doc reads:

> Scalar inputs are converted to 1-dimensional arrays, whilst
>   higher-dimensional inputs are preserved.

```
In [217]: np.atleast_1d(1)
Out[217]: array([1])
In [218]: np.atleast_1d([1,2,3])
Out[218]: array([1, 2, 3])
```

So your code simplifies to:

```
lat = np.atleast_1d(lat)
lon = np.atleast_1d(lon)
if lat.shape != lon.shape:
    <raise error>
```

Look at the code for `atleast_1d`; it's instructive.  Bascially it does:

```
lat = np.array(lat)
if len(lat.shape)==0:
   lat = lat.reshape(1)
```

Check for yourself what `np.array(1)` produces.

I could simplify it further with just one call to `atleast_1d`, since it takes multiple `inputs`:

```
lat, lon = np.atleast_1d(lat, lon)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a function to factorize some code:

```
def input_to_array(values):
    """Deal with scalar values as well as array-like objects.

    Convert them into numpy array.
    """
    try:
        single_value = float(values)
    except TypeError: # Trying to float() a list
        return np.array(values)
    except ValueError: # String does not contain a float
        # Return an array of strings, you can remove it if not needed.
        return np.array((values,))
    else:
        return np.array((single_value,))

lat = input_to_array(lat)
lon = input_to_array(lon)

if len(lat) != len(lon):
    raise ValueError("lat and lon arrays must be the same length")
```

Also note that you should provide the type of the exception you are expecting in an `except` clause or you would potentially be masking more serious problems.

And last, there might exist something more suited to numpy than `len()`.

Answer (score 1):

Mathias Ettinger already showed you some ways to clean up the code, but I have an important note. *Never* use a bare `except`. The rare occasion that you want to catch all exceptions you should still be passing in `except Exception` because otherwise `exit()` calls or `KeyboardInterrupt`s will be `excepted` and those are usually triggered manually. You should always try to `except` a specific error, one you're expecting could happen if the data is not of the intended form. Since `len()` failing raises a `TypeError`, you should use that.

```
try:
    lat_count = len(lat)
except TypeError:
    lat = [lat]
    lat_count = 1
```